# Set Array.capacity manualy?

Tags: arrays, swift, memory, capacity

I try to limit the memory allocation by Array. By default it is always upgraded to the next power of 2, e.g. instead of taking my value of 8577 it allocates 16376. How could I restrict it?

Comment: the important question is why do you want to restrict it?

Comment: There is `reserveCapacity`, but that doesn't guarantee that the *exact* amount of capacity is reserved. You can only give a minimum. It could allocate more for "better performance". Would that be okay for you?

Comment: I want to save memory! I know exactly how much elements I need. They are structures and they are large. And if I need 550.000 elements, there will be a request for more than a million!

Comment: I know reserveCapacity, but as you mentioned, it does not guarantee the size I requested. I need to set it by my own.